# How to implement a global filter search for React-Table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, react-table

I have a basic react-table component in where I want to filter through an input with multiple values/accessors (first name and last name). This is my code:

Columns:

```
const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      { Header: "First Name", accessor: "firstName" },
      { Header: "Last Name", accessor: "lastName" },
      { Header: "Address", accessor: "address" },
      { Header: "Company", accessor: "company" },
      { Header: "Phone Number", accessor: "phoneNumber" },
      { Header: "Email", accessor: "email" },
      { Header: "Sales", accessor: "sales.length" },
    ],
    []
  );
```

CustomersTable.js

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";

import { useTable, useFilters } from "react-table";

import "./DashboardUI.css";

const CustomersTable = ({ columns, data }) => {
  const [filterQuery, setFilterQuery] = useState("");

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    setFilter,
  } = useTable({ columns, data }, useFilters);

  const handleFilterChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value || undefined;
    // First name AND last name?
    setFilter("firstName", value);
    setFilterQuery(value);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <input
        className="customers-table-input"
        placeholder="Search by First Name"
        value={filterQuery}
        onChange={handleFilterChange}
      />
      <table {...getTableProps()} className="customers-table">
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                <th
                  {...column.getHeaderProps()}
                  className="customers-table-header"
                >
                  {column.render("Header")}
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.map((row) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr
                {...row.getRowProps()}
                onClick={() => console.log(row.original._id)}
                className="customers-table-row"
              >
                {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                  return (
                    <td
                      {...cell.getCellProps()}
                      className="customers-table-row-item"
                    >
                      {cell.render("Cell")}
                    </td>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default CustomersTable;
```

Currently, I am only able to filter by First name. I am using the useFilters hook and useState to capture the users query. Is there anyway setFilter can be used for multiple accessors?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe global filter is what you need?
https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useGlobalFilter